# Detect action of segmented control in a custom cell

Tags: ios, uisegmentedcontrol, detect, custom-cell

I got a simple question :

In a tableView, i'm displaying a list of customCells. These cells contain labels, SegmentedControllers....

The labels, segmentedController and other cells attributes are declared in a specific class.

How could I, in the class where the list it updated, detect if the segmented controller of the cells are modified? In this class, when I do something like :

```
if (cell.segmentedControl == 1) { DO MY THINGS }
```

...nothing ever happens.

Has anybody an advice? :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I'm pretty sure you need to use

```
(cell.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1)
```

with regards to knowing when it's been changed, use an IBAction connected to your cell class, set up a delegate on your view controller that will get a call back from the cell class when a cell control is clicked.

EDIT -----------------------
In your cell's class .h add

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<NSObject> delegate;
```

In the cell's class .m

```
@synthesize delegate = _delegate;

- (IBAction)segmentControlChanged
{
    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(segmentChanged:)]) {
        [self.delegate performSelector:@selector(segmentChanged:) withObject:self];
    }
}
```

In your ViewController that has the table, in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, add

```
cellname.delegate = self
```

and add the method

```
-(void)segmentChanged {
  // Put code here to refresh your data source
[self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: I meant...I forgot it here...Not in my code ;-)

So basically, what I already did : set an IBAction on the segmented controller, so my cell can see when the value is changed.

What I have to do : set up a delegate for the cell (but where? In the view controller of the cell?) then use this delegate in my tableView?

Comment: Ah sorry. I misunderstood. Yes, add a delegate var to the cell class and in your cellForRowAtIndexPath set cell.delegate=self then your cell can send a message back to your view controller. That in turn can message your data class if needed.

Comment: This question is 3 years old!